# SolvingBadUsage Exception in FileHelpers C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, filehelpers

I need to parse a fixed length txt file and convert it to XML. For that im trying to use the file helpers library.

My txt file looks somewhat like this. There are correct number of spaces between columns. Stackoverflow has removed them also textfiles cannot be posted here so this is the best I could do.

```
00000265287331ON      Gaurav lath                                                                                                                              WVWDM9AJ3BW054510         665300313                                          20160111                       

00000265412333AB      Kritin Kapoor                                                                                                                            WVWBA7AJ5AW423323         10100510855                                        20160111                       

00000265409491BC      Gary Kasprov                                                                                                                             WVWMN9AN2AE538477         773713F                                            20160111                       

00000265723428ON      ASBDHJW                                                                                                                                  3VWDX7AJ5BM008640         666760743                                          20160111                       

00003245782928AB      Damn bruh                                                                                                                                3VWDX7AJ7BM008526         10101931403                                        20160111                       

12345665842041NB      Ayeyeyeye Yoyoyoy                                                                                                                        3VWDX7AJ4BM317970         19498690                                           20160111                       

09876565877284ON      Sample Name                                                                                                                              3VWLX7AJ0BM004748         665727399                                          20160111                       

76542365887122AB      Dragutiin ivanovic                                                                                                                       WVWCA7AJ7BW072789         10102120532                                        20160111                       

09843266079601BC      Wayne Rooney                                                                                                                             3VW3L7AJ4BM014663         837089F                                            20160111                       

23049466096203SK      John Terry                                                                                                                               3VWBK7AJXBM311645         300656416                                          20160111
```

My main looks like this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var engine = new FixedFileEngine<VWDischargeTXT>();
        VWDischargeTXT[] result = engine.ReadFile("C:\\Users\\GL1676\\Desktop\\CSRSDischarge01112016.txt");

        foreach (var detail in result)
            Console.WriteLine(" AcctNum: {0},  Province: {1}", detail.AcctNum, detail.province);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Whenever I run the program a new windoe opens which highlights the path of the file and says

> BadUsageException was unhandled. End Of Line found processing the field: XYZ at line 2. (You need to mark it as [FieldOptional if you want to avoid this exception])

When I add the field as optional(even when it is not optional in any way and is in fact very important) there are a whole lot of other errors.

EDIT:
Here is the definition for VWDischargeTXT

```
[FixedLengthRecord()]
class VWDischargeTXT
{
    [FieldFixedLength(14)]
    public int AcctNum;

    [FieldFixedLength(8)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public char province;

    [FieldFixedLength(126)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public char CustomerName;

    [FieldFixedLength(26)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public char VIN;

    [FieldFixedLength(51)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public char RegNo;

    [FieldFixedLength(31)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
    public DateTime DischargeDate;
}
```

Comment: It might be another field that is missing but just getting loaded into the wrong field. There's not enough information to diagnose. Please edit your question and add the class definition for `VWDischargeTXT`. Also please ensure the data in your question matches your data file (you said it is 'somewhat' like that), and post as text formatted as code rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment as you were posting, you might not have noticed. I'll need to see some of your data (your `VWDischargeTXT` class doesn't match the data in the question at all so won't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, the spacing looks a little off in your question. I've edited it just to format the data as code, which looks to format it correctly (it seems well spaced).

Based on this edit, I've modified your `VWDischargeTXT` class so that it will work with the data. It becomes

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
class VWDischargeTXT
{
    [FieldFixedLength(14)]
    public long AcctNum;

    [FieldFixedLength(8)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string province;

    [FieldFixedLength(137)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string CustomerName;

    [FieldFixedLength(26)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string VIN;

    [FieldFixedLength(51)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string RegNo;

    [FieldFixedLength(31)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
    public DateTime DischargeDate;
}
```

Some notes:

- `FixedMode.AllowLessChars` is added to fix an error thrown
  complaining about the `DischargeDate` field on line 11. This may just
  be the formatting of the data in the question.
- `IgnoreEmptyLines` has been added to skip the blank lines. These blanks might just be the way it has been pasted into the question.
- The definition of `AcctNum` has been changed to `long`, as it is too large a number to be converted to an `int`.
- Your `char` fields have been changed to `string` as `char` is only used for single characters.
- The field length for `CustomerName` has been changed from `126` to `137` to match the data.

I've updated your code to show all the fields if you want to test

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FixedFileEngine<VWDischargeTXT>();
        VWDischargeTXT[] result = engine.ReadFile("C:\\Users\\GL1676\\Desktop\\CSRSDischarge01112016.txt");

        foreach (var detail in result)
            Console.WriteLine(" AcctNum: {0},  Province: {1}, CustomerName: {2}, VIN: {3}, RegNo: {4}, DischargeDate: {5}",
                detail.AcctNum, detail.province, detail.CustomerName, detail.VIN, detail.RegNo, detail.DischargeDate);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Any idea what this could mean?

 Line: 1 Column: 256. Not value found for the value type field: 'DischargeDate' Class: 'VWDischargeTXT'. 

You must use the [FieldNullValue] attribute because this is a value type and can't be null or use a Nullable Type instead of the current type.

Comment: It's saying it can't find a value for `DischargeDate` but I'm not sure why it's looking at column 256, did you change the field sizes on the class? (or change the data). If it is genuinely missing and optional then you can tell FileHelpers to allow nulls by defining the type as `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`